# How to add each digit in an integer

Tags: c++

This is the question, I have no idea how to do it

> 5. (7 points) Write an *int* function named *AddDigit* that takes an integer number as input It returns the sum of all digits which are
>      divisible by 3 or 5. For example,
>
> AddDigit(13579)    - it returns 17 (i.e 3+5+9) because 3, 5 and 9 are divisible by 3 or 5
>
> AddDigit(355)  - it returns 13 (i.e 3+5+5) because 3 and 5 are divisible by 3 or 5
>
> AddDigit(248)  - it returns 0 because no digit is divisible by 3 or 5

And this is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cstring>
    #include<time.h>
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int AddDigit(char a[]) {
        int sum = 0, numberofdigit;
        numberofdigit = strlen(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a)-1; i++) {
            if ((a[i] % 3 == 0 || a[i] % 5 == 0)&&a[i]!=0) {
                sum += a[i];
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
    int main() {
        char b[10];
        cin >> b;
        cout<<AddDigit(b);
     }
```

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: when I input 123, it gives me 50, but is should be 3

Comment: Use a debugger. In particular, look at the value of `a[i]`.

Comment: It seems that you are adding ascii code instead of digit

Comment: Why is b type char?

Comment: and maybe you should use std::string instead of char array in this approach

Comment: The ASCII value of '2' is 50. Also you are only looping through the first 2 characters

Comment: The assignment asks for an integer, not a character sequence.  The sending of either a char array or `std::string` to the `AddDigit` function seems to violate the assignment's instructions.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  If so, then this is easily solved without strings or character arrays.  All you need to do is pass the integer, and write a routine that goes through each digit of the integer and tests to see if it is divisible by 3 or 5.  Extracting a digit from an integer is widely known (a simple loop that does modulus 10 of the number, and continuous division by 10 of the number).

Comment: @UJChan If this is a homework assignment, I could post an answer, but did you earn those "7 points" if I did that?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is the past paper question, I am going to have C++ exam on next Monday.

Answer (score 3):

You are giving the input as a char array, a character '0' is different from an integer 0,
ASCII of '0' which is  48
ASCII of 0 which is 0
Why you got 50 for '123' because '2' means 50%5==0, so you added '2' to the sum.

To get what u wanted, you need to get the integer equivalent of the char array with d = arr[i]-'0'

```
   int AddDigit(char a[]) {
        int sum = 0, numberofdigit;
        numberofdigit = strlen(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++) {
            int d = a[i]-'0';
            if ((d % 3 == 0 || d % 5 == 0)&&d!=0) {
                sum += d;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: You could also use a conversion function like atoi() http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: the questions is to find the sum of individual digits, how does atoi helps here?

Comment: it converts the characters to integers

Comment: @praveen The assignment states -- *Write an int function named AddDigit that takes an integer number* .  Your answer sends a character sequence to `AddDigit`, not an `int` or integer argument.

Comment: The OP did not mention that before i posted the comment, i just rectified the error in the code that was written by him.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the assignment, the `AddDigit` function is supposed to take an `int` argument, not a character array, string, or any other character-based type.  Thus your approach starts out incorrectly, since it violates the assignment's requirements.

So the approach is to figure out how to strip each digit from an `int`, and from that digit, determine if it is evenly divisible by 3 or 5.  Using simple modulus and continuous division of the passed-in integer, an approach can be something like this:

```
int AddDigit(int n)
{
    int total = 0; // final total
    while (n > 0)
    {
        int digit = n % 10; // get rightmost digits

        // add the value if digit is either evenly divisible by 3 or 5
        total += ((digit % 3 == 0 || digit % 5 == 0) ? digit : 0);

        // remove the last digit from the number
        n /= 10;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Note that the line that adds to the total will add 0 if the ternary condition returns `false`.  That condition is to check if either the digit is evenly divisible by 3 or 5.  If the condition is `true`, we simply add that digit onto the total.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bit more neatly done in a recursive function:

```
int AddDigit(int num)
{
    if (num == 0)  //WE REACH THIS WHEN 1-DIGIT NUMBER IS DIVIDED BY 10
            return 0;

    int curNum = num % 10;  //ALWAYS ACCOUNTING FOR ONLY LAST DIGIT


    //WE ADD IT OR NOT AND THEN CONTINUE TO THE NEXT DIGIT

    if (curNum % 3 == 0 || curNum % 5 == 0)
            return curNum + AddDigit(num/10);
    else
            return AddDigit(num/10);


}
```

Comment: `int AddDigit(int n){return "0003056009"[n%10]-'0'+(n?AddDigit(n/10):0);}` ;)

Comment: @paddy count me as impressed!